# How to correctly import and use an interface in typescript?

Tags: oop, typescript

I want to use an interface for my data.
**forms.interface.ts**

```
interface Field {
    name: string;
    style: string;
}

interface Form {
    name: string;
    visible_name: string;
    default: string;
    fields: Field[];
}

interface Interface {
    form: Form;
}

export interface RootInterface {
    interface: Interface[];
}
```

I tried this...

```
import {RootInterface} from "../int/form.protorype.interface"
export class MainServiceProvider {
    private form:RootInterface;
```

If I try to allocate var for this interface `private _generatordata:RootInterface`
there is a compiler exception with error `Type 'RootInterface' is not an array type or a
string type`

Comment: How are you initializing this `_generatordata` member?

Comment: yep, i initializing that try use demo data, but i see that err

Comment: No no, I asked HOW are you initializing it? please edit your question and show that part of your code.